# Why is property declared in a constructor of a class not exist?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
constructor (service: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.init();
}
```

In the above code, I'm getting:-

```
Property `service` does not exist on type 'MyComponment'
```

Yet, if I declare `service` as `private` it works. What is going on here?

--

[Angular 8.2.12, TypeScript 3.5.3]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties):

> Parameter properties are declared by prefixing a constructor parameter
> with an accessibility modifier or `readonly`, or both. Using `private`
> for a parameter property declares and initializes a private member;
> likewise, the same is done for `public`, `protected`, and `readonly`.

Without the prefix, the constructor parameter is nothing more than a method parameter, and you would have to manually assign it to a declared class property from the constructor itself.

[Related SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53075211/5621827)

Comment: First link deprecated by this one: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

> Property `service` does not exist on type 'MyComponment'

Error is because you are trying to access `service` outside of the class's constructor. And by design if you are willing to use some variable/initilization outside the constructor you have to use some access modifiers like `private` `public` etc.

```
   constructor (private service: MyService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.init();  // valid
    }
```

Here

```
constructor (service: MyService) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.init();  // Invalid
}
```

`ngOnInit` is outside/different method of the class not inner from the constructor so in order to access using `this` keyword you have to use some access modifier prefix while initilization in the constructor.

But this will work if you do it like this -

```
constructor (service: MyService) {
    service.init();  // valid
}
```

In simpler words you can follow this small example -

- https://kendaleiv.com/typescript-constructor-assignment-public-and-private-keywords/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean putting the `private` like this:

```
constructor (private service: MyService) {}
```

That's actually a shorthand in TypeScript.

Similar to

```
constructor (public service: MyService) {}
```

Its sugar so you don't have to do

```
class Foo {
  private foo
  public bar
  constructor (foo, bar) {
    this.foo = 1
    this.bar = 2
  }
}
```

Instead you would do:

```
class Foo {
  constructor (private foo = 1, public bar = 2) {}
}
```

When the TypeScript is compiled into JS, it puts both public and privates as *regular* (public) instance properties. Because JS doesn't actually have the concept of private class members ([not yet anyway](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields))